# what kind of language is that?

Tags: c#

I received a piece of code but I cannot understand what kind of language it is. It looks like C# but C# uses the "using" clause in order to import a library where on this programming language file it uses a "use" clause. I cannot find any information about the "use" clause and I am actually confused because this programming language looks like C#/Java/Visual Basic but on these languages I cannot find the use of the "use" clause. The weird thing is that the code doesn't use any methods and the file I received had a .txt extension.

**the file starts like that:**

```
use Collection, File, Stream, String, System;
use Date;
include globals.routines.global_routines_generic;
include globals.routines.global_routines_mcc;
include globals.routines.global_classifier;
```

**after that they declare a bunch of variables with the "var" clause and then a part of code looks like that:**

```
File.createFolder(settings.path_files);

foreach(i, Folder in Folders) {
    if (dlc.allfolders || String.contains(Folder, dlc.specific_folder)) {
        Bestanden       = File.iterateFiles(Folder.path, true);
        stop_word_list  = load_stop_words();
        foreach(j, Bestand in Bestanden) {
            if (rerun) {
                if (!String.contains(Bestand, "ONBEKEND")) {
                    continue ;
                }
            }
            writeAuditTrail     (logfile, String.join(["Processing file " , Bestand]), 0, savelog);

folder_items        = String.split(Bestand, "\\\\", false);
        last_folder_name    = folder_items[Collection.length(folder_items)-2];
        dossier_tab         = get_dossier_tab(folder_items[Collection.length(folder_items)-1], dlc);
        possible_docs       = dlc.HR_dossier_tabs[dossier_tab];
```

Does anyone have any idea what kind of language is that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: ask the individual who gave you the code.. this looks like could be `c or C++ or even Java`

Comment: `foreach(a, b)`, `include` and `use` are all present in the xillio platform (ETL) scripting language https://support.xillio.com/support/solutions/articles/6000061410-basic-syntax

Comment: Extensions are (basically) meaningless here. They could have put a .jpg or .exe or whatever and it wouldn't have made a difference.

Comment: As a correction to your original statement, "using" doesn't import a library in C#, it just tells the compiler which namespaces to search for classes. The framework won't *actually* import the DLL until it's actually needed. It's also definitely *not* the case that "namespace = DLL" (EXEs have namespaces too and they're obviously not DLLs) or even "namespace = assembly" (there may be several namespaces in a single assembly).

Answer (score 1):

The code is closest to c++. It is definitely not java due to the fact that java does not have the foreach loop, the use keyword, and var. It is also probably not C# because of the library include syntax. It could be low level pseudo code but it is unlikely due to the syntax being so close to a C based language. [enter link description here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword)